# OAuth2.0 in mongoose-auth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, everyauth

I have authentication working well with mongoose-auth in node.js.  Would like to connect to Google REST Api that requires OAuth2.0 authentication. Does mongoose-auth support OAuth2?

(added everyauth as tag as mongoose-auth doesn't exist yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose-auth extends everyauth which does implement OAuth2.0ds